# Cannot execute virtualenv commands when using Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to set up a virtual environment for a Django project, using Python 2.7. Both Python 2.7 and 3.6 are installed on my Mac.

I run the command, specifying the path to Python 2.7 `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 venv` and everything seems to work fine. However, when I run `venv source/bin/activate` it tells me `venv: command not found`.

Something is broken. I have read similar answers on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to be working. I have installed and uninstalled `virtualenv` with `pip`, tried running with superuser etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need `source venv/bin/activate`. `source` is a command, `venv` is the directory your virtualenv is located in.